# R: Plot multiple time series in a loop.Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, loops, plot, time-series

I'm trying to plot many time series from a database with 134 columns, one ts per colum and after that, save it in a .jpg file. I'm using a loop. I notice that the ploblem could be the `plot()` function.

Some data with `dput()`

```
 structure(list(X9003 = c(3L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
 3L), X9004 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L), X9007 = c(5L, 
 8L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 5L), X9009 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L), X9010 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, 3L, 15L), X9012 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
 ), X9014 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
 NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
 NA_integer_), X9016 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 27L, 7L, 
 12L), X9019 = c(3L, 8L, 27L, 38L, 19L, 27L, 25L, 47L, 5L, 3L), 
 X9020 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And

```
dput(dat_nombres[1:10,1:2])
structure(list(ESTACIONES = c(9003L, 9004L, 9007L, 9009L, 9010L, 
9012L, 9014L, 9016L, 9019L, 9020L), CLAVE = c(9003L, 9004L, 9007L, 
9009L, 9010L, 9012L, 9014L, 9016L, 9019L, 9020L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
  data<- read.csv("GranizoAnualCompleto_1961-2019_columnas.csv", header = 
   TRUE)
    dat_nombres<-read.csv("Nombres_Estaciones_CLICOM.csv", header=TRUE )
    Estaciones<-dat_nombres$ESTACIONES  # List
    Estacionestmp<-data[,-1]

    # Loop

    for (i in seq_along (Estacionestmp)) { 
      serie<-ts(Estacionestmp[,i], start = 1961, frequency = 1)
      mypath<-file.path("C:","00 FENIX","03 Data", "Data_Est_Select_1961- 
       2019", "SeriesTiempo_GranizoAnual",  
                paste("Ts_Granizo4_", Estaciones[i],".jpg", sep = "")) 
      jpeg(filename = mypath)  

      plot(serie,
         col="darkblue",
         main="Días con granizo 1961-2019 \n Estación", Estaciones[i] ,
         cex.main=2,
         sub=paste("Estación",Estaciones[i]),
         cex.sub= 1.5,
         col.main="darkred",
         xlab= "Tiempo",
         ylab= "Días con granizo",
         cex.lab=0.8,
         col.axis= "gray34",
         col.lab= "gray25",
         type= "l"
         )
       dev.off() }
```

The error message are:

```
      Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
      'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

But when I just code `plot(serie)` (without any details in the plot function) in the loop, there are no ploblem with the result and the files are created in the specific path that I have defined. Recently, I used this code but on a dataframe with 20 columns and it worked.

Why that details in the plot function argument are causing the error message? How can I fix the loop for create multiple time series plots? Is there any better solution to do it?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I find that the problem are when I trying to change the main for name and subpaste every plot, the problem with the `Estaciones[i]`; I prove write a `#` before for comment it, and now it works! So, I converted it to a list

```
  Estaciones_list<-as.list(Estaciones)
```

and tried with this new list in the main for every plot but it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What is *Estaciones*? You only show *Estacionestmp*.

Comment: I edited my question, you are right, thanks. It's a list for name my files in the loop. Sorry!

Comment: Please provide `dput` of *dat_nombres*. Your loop through columns defines *i* as column number but use *i* for row number. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just edited the question and put the information of dput(); I find the problem when I trying to change the name of every plot.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment: "Your loop through columns defines i as column number but use i for row number."

Comment: Please test your posted data and code and make sure it reproduces your error/undesired result. What you post throws different errors. Remember we do not have see any of you csv data. Always test code and data in a new R session before posting on SO.